# can't seem to use 'first()' on Observable(rxjs in Angular)

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I read about this awesome feature in RXJS which would theoretically allow me to subscribe only for one response, but can't seem to implement it. Instead, I'm getting this error,

> "Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Observable'."

although I am just copy-pasting from existing examples. 
Here's my code:

```js
implementHash( token ){
    console.log('trying to implement hash', token);
    const req = this.http.get('http://localhost:3003/token/' + token );
    const sub = req
        //.first()
        .subscribe( res =>{
            sub.unsubscribe; // trying to avoid this line
    });
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'`;

in your file.

Comment: Sorry did not notice this

Comment: @Sajeetharan :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add  `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'` to your component.ts file.

It comes from the import first.